# Omission of "IF

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

1. I am speaking in such a way where someone was 50 feet away from me , they would hear it.
2. I am speaking in such a way where **if** someone was 50 feet away from me, they  would hear it.

I think the "if" in the second sentence should be omitted and is unnecessary. If so, why is "if" used in the second sentence?

Comment: I would not use _where_ in that way in either sentence. I would say _in such a way **that if** someone ..._ I would probably also use _were_ rather than _was_ (counter-factual conditional) but not everybody uses that form.

Comment: @ColinFine That would make a good answer.

Comment: And if there is a comma after *me* I'd also put one before *if*.

Comment: Both your sentences are incorrect, with or without the "if".  The correct expression is the one by @ColinFine above: "... that if someone were 50 feet away ... they would hear it".

Comment: Also, "speaking in such a way" sounds a little clumsy in the context, as does the "it" at the end (where really you mean "me").  A native speaker would likely rephrase the whole sentence as: "I'm speaking so loudly that if someone were 50 feet away, they would hear me".